# nativescript-audio plugin does not function on ios

Tags: audio, plugins, nativescript

I have succesfully implemented the nativescript-audio plugin on android. I am using plain JS in my project. When i run it on ios i get the following error.

> NSURLErrorDomain Code= -1002 "unsupported url".

I get this error with most of the examples that i found on the web (including the following , which works perfectly on android).

```
var ns_audio = require("nativescript-audio");

var player = new ns_audio.TNSPlayer();

var playerOptions = {
        audioFile: "http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2514.mp3",
        loop: false,
        completeCallback: function () {
            console.log('completePlayer')
        },
        errorCallback: function (errorObject) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errorObject));
        },
        infoCallback: function (args) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
        }
    };

player.playFromUrl(playerOptions)
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function () {
            console.log("didn't work...");
        })
```

It looks like recording works (no errors, and the correct responses, although i cannot test if the file has been correctly created...) But playback gives this error.  Any idea ?

Comment: Have you enabled `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in your info plist which whitelists all Http urls to be used within your app?

Comment: I did, thanks. It was not the problem though!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plain JS [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=1IEYu0) for you. I have tested the mp3 URL that you have provided in the the post and that works fine on ios. 
Have a play with that and see if you are missing something. Here is

```
function pageLoaded(args) {

  var page = args.object;


  const player = new audio.TNSPlayer();
  const playerOptions = {
    audioFile: 'http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2514.mp3',
    loop: false,
    completeCallback: function () {
      console.log('finished playing');
    },
    errorCallback: function (errorObject) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(errorObject));
    },
    infoCallback: function (args) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
    }
  };

  player
    .playFromUrl(playerOptions)
    .then(function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('something went wrong...', err);
    });
  page.bindingContext = homeViewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recording and Playback with the nativescript-audio plugin (for iOS) are both working now!. My first problem was that i needed to record to .caf (not .mp3) so i used

```
if(isAndroid)
{ 
    extention = ".mp3"; 
}
else 
{ 
    extention = ".caf"; 
}
```

before i record the audio file....

Also i ran in a stupid oversight which is easy to miss.... 
i created my code from the above mentioned example, but because i play the sound that is recorded to a .caf file. i needed to use playFromFile and not playFromUrl as the example uses. 
( thats what caused the error : NSURLErrorDomain Code= -1002 "unsupported url".)

```
 player
    .playFromFile(playerOptions)
    .then(function (res) {
```

hopefully this point of attention can save someone a headache !